# "Incompatible types. Found: int Required: boolean" on a switch

Tags: java, android

I created a `switch` which takes an `int`, and then specified some `case`s for it.

The problem I'm getting is that, when I put the `int` values, I get the error `Incompatible types. Found: int, Required: Boolean`. Why does that happen? Does `switch` need a `Boolean`? If so, how can I adapt the following code?

```
Random generatori4 = new Random();
                int ii4 = generatori4.nextInt(16) + 1;

                switch (ii4) {
                    case ( ii4 == 1 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa33);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 2 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa34);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 3 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa35);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 4 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa36);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 5 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa37);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 6 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa38);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 7 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa39);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 8 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa40);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 9 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa41);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 10 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa42);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 11 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa43);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 12 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa44);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 13 ) :
                        pregunta.setText(Europa45);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 14 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa46);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 15 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa47);
                        break;
                    case ( ii4 == 16 ):
                        pregunta.setText(Europa48);
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it. If not, please post a comment and let me know why. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Problem

Like the error says, Python expects to see matching types in your `switch` and in your `case` statements. But it doesn't. Why? Because `switch (ii4)` means, "Do something depending on the value of `ii4`, which I told you above is an `int`." But your case statements contain equalities like `ii4 == 1`, which is a `Boolean`. Et voilà, there's your error.

## The Solution

Remove the equalities from your `case`s. You've already specified that you want to look at values for your variable with `switch (ii4)`, so you don't need to say `ii4 == x`. You just need to say `x`.

So, for example, change

```
case( ii4 == 1 ):
```

to

```
case 1:
```

You might want to read [the tutorial on `switch` statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).